# Specific split record (string) into several fields

Tags: mysql, sql, string, split

I've got strings with text like this:

> "Australia/Sydney/Day 2738/Jose and Carlin"

I need to split it to several columns. But here's the tricky part. String also may be looks like

> "UK/Manchester/Centre/Day 627/Lucas and Nicole".

All strings have one template, i think:

> "%/%/D%/% and %"

And i need move each of "%" to another field/column.

> "UK" , "Manchester/Centre" , "Day 627" , "Lucas" , "Nicole"

inb4: using mysql 5.5
Thanks!
Nik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have a split function for strings, but [here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) you can see an user-defined function that you can use to do your job.

For example:

```
select SPLIT_STR(SPLIT_STR(ColumnA, "/D",1), "/", 1),
CONCAT(SPLIT_STR(SPLIT_STR(ColumnA, "/D",1), "/", 2),'/',
   SPLIT_STR(SPLIT_STR(ColumnA, "/D",1), "/", 3)),
CONCAT('D',SPLIT_STR(SPLIT_STR(ColumnA, "/D",2), "/", 1)),
SPLIT_STR(SPLIT_STR(ColumnA, "/D",2), "/", 2)
from table1
```

OUTPUT ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f1be/12)):

```
Australia   Sydney/             Day 2738    Jose and Carlin
UK          Manchester/Centre   Day 627     Lucas and Nicole
```

Comment: I've got several delimetters because of dynamic second filed. It can contains the delimetter "/" as i showd in second example. Can the SPLIT_STR handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if MySQL natively can do it. but you can add a user defined function to do it, easier if you have fixed number of fields delimited by /. Sort of hard if you want it dynamic solution, and even that would have to be taken care in your scripting language than query.

Just a little direction if it helps: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: I got an update while composing my answer. but good stuff..that post is really nice. but you should always give credit to source and hence I posted the URL.

Comment: I posted the URL of the author in my first answer... Check the link, and see it yourself...